# Change image of UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller

I need to set a different image for the more button in the `UITabBar` in Swift 2.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
let more = tabBarController.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem
more.image = UIImage(named: "squadra")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Really thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from interface builder as follows:

Open document outline and select tab bar item as follows:

[image]

Then change image property of bar item from attribute inspector to appropriate xcasset as follows:

[image]

Finally your image of tab bar item will be changed[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBarController.tabBar.items?.first?.image = UIImage(named: "squadra")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I need only for the more tab, the others are ok.

Comment: If your More tab is last one then use `tabBarController.tabBar.items?.last?`

Comment: no: i have 7 tabs, the tabs from 5 to 7 are collected into the "More" tab... That's the icon image I need to change...